# Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager; Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager;

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Trying to run a module example for class, I have updated the gradle build version to 3.0.1 and compiledsdkversion to 25 and changed the targetSDKVersion to 27.

This application should open without any problems.

To get an original version go to URL https://www.murach.com/images/downloads/android_programming_2nd_ed/and2_allfiles.zip

Any help would be appreciated. I updated Android Studios earlier today, and now previous working programs aren't running and showing the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. To get more information from these error messages, I directly invoked `gradle` (`gradle installArm7Debug`) instead of calling `gradlew` from the command line.

Try to build your project from the command line to get more information.

My issue - in case you have the same - was I did not have the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` defined (and also `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` because I was also using Android NDK).
So make sure the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` is correctly defined in your environment.